# Trying to delete row using pdo statement where row item matches php variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to receive text input and store it as a variable. Then I use PDO to execute a query that deletes a row from a MySQL database that contains text that matches the text stored in the variable. Obviously this is not working. My usual suspect is my query.  I have also been toying with binding params but that didn't work either.

```
 <?php
     if (isset($_POST['gigDate'])){

            $gigDate  = $_POST['gigDate'];

               if (!empty($gigDate)){

                   require_once("dbconnect.php");
                   $query = $connect->prepare("DELETE * FROM 'gigs' WHERE 'date'='".$gigDate."'");
                   $query->execute(); 

                   }
               else 
                    {
                       echo "failure";
                      }
               require_once('gui.php');
                }
   ?>
```

This is my html form

```
   <h3>Delete a gig by date. (copy and paste gig date)</h3>

   <?php include ("gigDelete.php");?>

   <form action="gigDelete.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="gigDate"></input>
   <button type="submit" value="Delete" name="Delete">delete gig</button>
   </form>
```

I have had one error message that stated that my error reporting wasn't working. haha.  So I removed it.  I only just learned PDO last week and I am unsure if it is appropriate for this task..  How my inexperience shines!

This is the last part of my first ever php GUI. I can upload to the database just dandy and I am displaying the data in a html table which is also working.  So I can assume I'm connecting to the db.

Comment: For one thing, you're using the wrong [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) for both your table and column. Plus, get rid of the `*`. Read up on the function => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: What's the point of using prepared statements if you are hardcoding the values?

Comment: Add `$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened and you will see the errors.

Comment: The * is gone.  I should point out that i am not on localhost.  The site is live. I received a request to add this delete functionality. So I am uploading to test. Is this bad practice?

Comment: Is it working from you now, as per the answers given? Most of which are incorrect. Bad practice? Your code is full of syntax errors that I've already pointed out. Have you looked into anything I've said above?

Comment: I have $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); already included and it gives me no errors.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then. You'll see them. Did you change the identifiers? You also need to change `prepare` to `query`, you're not using prepared statements.

Comment: I have changed the identifiers and added the error reporting.  I am receiving an error message stating that I have a PDO problem.

Comment: $query = $connect->prepare("DELETE FROM 'gigs' WHERE 'date'= :date");
            $query->bindParam(':date', $gigDate);
            $query->execute();           I just tried this with no success.

Comment: You're still using quotes. Please take it up with the answers given below and tell them why it's not working. They have no idea whether it's working or not. You need to interact with them.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!  Those damn backticks.  thanks again Fred -ii- for sending me in the right direction.  I owe you some free drum tracks on your next album.  I'm learning to code to make a website for my band.  Old dog, new trick.

Comment: You're welcome, *I aims to please* ;-) Glad to know there's another smiling face in this world. I might take you up on that too ♫~ cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, why you are using extra `single quotes` for table and column names? The identifier quote character is the backtick (**`**)

```
DELETE FROM  `gigs` WHERE date='".$gigDate."'
```

Comment: I've didn't even know backticks existed until right now.

Comment: nevermind bro, it is enough to know that "Stackoverflow Exists..", ha ha best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$query = $connect->prepare("DELETE FROM gigs WHERE date='".$gigDate."'");
```

Btw, if you are using PDO, there is no good reason to hardcode values like that.

Comment: This will fail, being the `*` in `DELETE * FROM`

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will work for you:

```
$query = $connect->prepare("DELETE * FROM 'gigs' WHERE 'date'= :date");
$query->bindParam(':date', $gigDate);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: I'll give it a crack.

Comment: I tried it and no success. I can assume that the PDO is not the problem.

Comment: This will fail for two reasons.

Comment: Wrong identifiers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html and not the way to delete http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html - See the accepted answer.